# Coordinates of centre, equilateral triangle

Tags: java, implementation

My current triangle class looks like:

```
public class TriangleEquilateral {
    private Point cornerA;
    private Point cornerB;
    private Point cornerC;
    private double x1 = 0;
    private double y1 = 0;
    private double x2 = 10;
    private double y2 = 0;
    private double x3 = 5;
    private double y3 = Math.sqrt(75);

    public TriangleEquilateral(){
        cornerA = new Point(x1,y1);
        cornerB = new Point(x2,y2);
        cornerC = new Point(x3,y3);
    }

    public TriangleEquilateral(double X1,double Y1,double X2,double Y2,double X3,double Y3){
        x1 = X1;
        y1 = Y1;
        x2 = X2;
        y2 = Y2;
        x3 = X3;
        y3 = Y3;

        cornerA = new Point(X1,Y1);
        cornerB = new Point(X2,Y2);
        cornerC = new Point(X3,Y3);
    }

    public boolean isEquilateral(){
        double lengthAB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
        double lengthBC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x3,2) + Math.pow(y2-y3,2));
        double lengthCA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x1,2) + Math.pow(y3-y1,2));

        boolean isEquilateral = false;
        if(lengthAB == lengthBC && lengthBC == lengthCA && lengthCA == lengthAB){
            isEquilateral = true;
        }
        System.out.println(lengthAB);
        System.out.println(lengthBC);
        System.out.println(lengthCA);
        return isEquilateral;
    }

    public double sideLength(){
        double sL = 0;
        if(this.isEquilateral() == true){
            sL = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
        }
        return sL;
    }
```

How would I determine the coordinates of the midpoint of an equilateral triangle? I know that the midpoint is **x = (base/2)**, **y = heigth/2** but this only works if the base is horizontal(two corners have the same y value)

Comment: This isn't a Java or even a programming question but rather a *math* question. Have you looked at a math site or Wikipedia on this? Have you tried to work this out on paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For equilateral triangle, coordinates of the triangle's center are the same as the coordinates of the center of its incircle.

Look up [the formula for the incircle's center on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Coordinates_of_the_incenter):

```
{ (aXa+bXb+cXc)/(a+b+c), (aYa+bYb+cYc)/(a+b+c) }
```

Since `a = b = c`, it is easy to see that the coordinates of the center of an equilateral triangle are simply

```
{ (x0+x1+x2)/3, (y0+y1+y2)/3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Math question than a java question. Anyway, to find the barycenter:

```
x = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3
y = (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3
```